# How do I display an array inside a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the code :

```
list = ["Alex","John","Kit","Lenny"];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $("body").append("<p> list[i] </p>');
};
```

Look at the for loop(yes this is using jquery),i want to add the list items inside the paragraph headers.How do i do it ?

Comment: `$("body").append("<p>" + list[i] + " </p>")` or `$("body").append(['<p>',list[i],'</p>'].join())`

Comment: basic string concatenation or use ES6 templates

Comment: should be fairly obvious where problem is when you look at current results

Answer (score 1):

`list[i]` is not a string, it's a variable. To include it into the appended element, close the quotation marks in following way:

```js
var list = ["Alex","John","Kit","Lenny"];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $("body").append("<p>" + list[i] + "</p>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```